# Area of the shaded part in rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

[image: area problem]
The question asks you to determine the shaded part of the rectangle in terms of x.

please will someone help with this problem, i have spent a while on it with not much progress.

Comment: Have you stated the problem completely? If you had the width of the rectangle, W, say, then the area is clearly 14W - 3W = 11W (the unshaded triangle has area 3W).  But x , the length of the chord, does not determine W.  Indeed you can rotate that chord pretty freely and preserve your picture while changing W.

Comment: That "8" seems misplaced (serving no purpose at the moment).

Comment: This is the complete problem. There is no other given information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the information in the picture, $x$ does not uniquely define the area of the gray area, therefore it is impossible to express the area only in terms of $x$.